# Generalized Trigonometric Functions in terms of exponentials and roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, special-functions, exponential-function

I am trying to come up with generalized trigonometric functions using the exponential definition that we use today for the trig functions sine and cosine
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i};   \cos x =\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
I was then thinking, in terms of roots of unity, if we define
$$\omega_n^k=e^\frac{2ki\pi}{n}$$
Then
$$\cos x =\frac{(\omega_4^0)^0e^{\omega_4^1x}+(\omega_4^2)^0e^{\omega_4^3x}}{2\omega_4^0};\sin x =\frac{(\omega_4^0)^1e^{\omega_4^1x}+(\omega_4^2)^1e^{\omega_4^3x}}{2\omega_4^1}$$
Then I could extend as say 
$$C_0(x)=\frac{(\omega_6^0)^0e^{\omega_6^1x}+(\omega_6^2)^0e^{\omega_6^3x}+(\omega_6^4)^0e^{\omega_6^5x}}{3\omega_6^0}$$
$$C_1(x)=\frac{(\omega_6^0)^1e^{\omega_6^1x}+(\omega_6^2)^1e^{\omega_6^3x}+(\omega_6^4)^1e^{\omega_6^5x}}{3\omega_6^1}$$
$$C_2(x)=\frac{(\omega_6^0)^2e^{\omega_6^1x}+(\omega_6^2)^2e^{\omega_6^3x}+(\omega_6^4)^2e^{\omega_6^5x}}{3\omega_6^2}$$
I've seen generalizations for trig function using the integral definition of the inverses, and i've seen the defined using lacunary power series.  WOuld this be another way to define a trig generalization?

Comment: All the expressions in question are combinations of hyperbolic and trigonometric functions.

Comment: Thank you.  I've seen how higher order trig functions have been defined using the hyperbolic and trig function combinations.  I was just wondering if there has been a generalized symmetric exponential definition

Comment: I recently came across this article which did what you asked. It seems that there are some other applications on those 'higher order trig functions' https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17302172